# Django: Gmail SMTP error: please run connect() first

Tags: python, django, email, smtplib

I am trying to send mail when a certain query is executed. But I am getting error in the connection. I have tried the following settings in my settings.py file

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com')
server.starttls()
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "email@gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "password"
server.login(EMAIL_HOST_USER, EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD)
```

I have executed the following command to send the email:

```
emailFrom = [settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER]
html_content = render_to_string('template.html', {'greeting_text': greeting_text})
text_content = strip_tags(html_content)
email_subject = "Subject"
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(email_subject,text_content,emailFrom,[email],)
msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
msg.send()
```

But whenever I run the above code I get 'please run connect() first' error.
What is the error Exactly about and how do I solve this?

Comment: Where are you running that from? The django shell? And could you post the full exception message, please?

Comment: I am currently running this from python shell. Full message is just `please run connect() first`

Comment: Try running it from `python manage.py shell`

Comment: I got the same error

Comment: Is there any error with my connections setting??

Comment: I don't really understand your settings, where is `EMAIL_HOST` and `EMAIL_USE_TLS`? And what is your `EMAIL_BACKEND`? ([Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/email/#smtp-backend)). Your `server` object isn't something Django uses to send mail, so you might as well remove those lines.

Comment: `EMAIL_HOST ="smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "email@gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "passwod"
EMAIL_PORT = 0
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False` I used this at first but it shows `SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server` error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you have all the email settings configured:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```